# Logstash keep syslog host

Tags: logstash, syslog

I have a syslog server and the ELK stack on the same server. I have a directory for each syslog source.
I'm trying to parse syslog files with Logstash, and I'd like to keep the ip adress or the hostname of the syslog source in the "host" field. At the moment I have the 0.0.0.0 source after Logstash parsing.

My logstash.conf :

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["path/to/file.log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "linux-syslog"
    ignore_older => 0
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "linux-syslog" {
    grok {
      match => {"message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["@IP_Elastic:Port_Elastic"]
  }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: please update your question with an example syslog message

Comment: A syslog message could be :
`Jan 12 06:30:00 1.2.3.4 apache_server: 1.2.3.4 - - [12/Jan/2011:06:29:59 +0100] "GET /foo/bar.html HTTP/1.1" 301 96 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)" PID 18904 Time Taken 0 `
I don't have source IP address of the log or the hostname inside the log, however as I store logs in a directory for each source, I'd like to use the name of these directories to set the "host" field in Logstash

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite your host with your ip variable once you have parsed it. Consider this example:

```
Pipeline main started
{"ip":"1.2.3.4"}
{
       "message" => "{\"ip\":\"1.2.3.4\"}",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-08-10T13:36:18.875Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
            "ip" => "1.2.3.4",
         "@host" => "1.2.3.4"
}
```

I am parsing json to get the IP. Then I write the IP field into the host.

The filter:

```
filter {
    # this parses the ip json
    json {
        source => "message"
    }

    mutate {
        add_field => { "@host" => "%{ip}" }
    }
}
```

replace %{ip} with whatever field contains your ip address.

Cheers,
Artur